# How to get rid of the vacant weekend in the candlestick chart

Tags: activex, teechart

I've read some articles about the weekend problem with teechart and the suggestions are  the foolowing steps:

1. `TChart1.Series(0).XValues.DateTime = False`
2. Use continuous numbers as Xvalues
3. replace the X label with datetime.

The problem is: I draw the real time candlesticks according to the date,hour and minute and I must keep  TChart1.Series(0).XValues.DateTime = True

So are there any ways to get rid of the null weekend (not only the weekend, even some time in a day as from 5:15 to 6:00 need to be removed) so that the candlesticks are shown continuously (the Xvalues must keep datetime style all the time)?

thanks.

(BTW, I use Teechart2011 Eval & VB6)

Answer (score 0):

TeeChart draws each point according to its X and Y values in the associated axes.
You can work with Break Axis tool to obtain a discontinuous effect in an axis, but the easiest way to draw the points continuously in the horizontal axis is having continuous X values. So I'd suggest you to use the `TChart1.Series(i).asCandle.AddCandle XVal, OpenVal, HighVal, LowVal, CloseVal, Label, clTeeColor` function, being:

- XVal: `TChart1.Series(i).Count`, instead of the date retrieved from the system
- Label: the date retrieved from the system, converted to string

If this doesn't solve the problem because you still think you must have DateTime XValues, please explain why.

Comment: With TChart1.Series(0)
.asCandle.AddCandle .Count, _
              arrValues(i, 1), arrValues(i, 2), arrValues(i, 3), arrValues(i, 4), CStr(DateValue(month & "," & day & "," & year) + TimeValue(hour & ":" & minute & ":" & second)), clTeeColor
end with

But I was told with wrong parameters, so what is the right label here, also, my date include both the date and time retrieved from the system.

Comment: Are Month, Day, Year, Hour, Minute and Second the functions? If so, note they expect a Date parameter, ie: Month(Now). The following seems to work fine for me here:   Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To 9
    TChart1.Series(0).asCandle.AddCandle i, Rnd * 5 + 5, Rnd * 5, Rnd * 5 + 15, Rnd * 5 + 10, CStr(DateValue(Month(Now) & "," & Str$(i + 1) & "," & Year(Now))), clTeeColor
  Next i

Answer (score 0):

Taking your snipped of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732336/how-to-get-rid-of-the-vacant-weekend-in-the-candlestick-chart-01), I've created a simple example that seems to work fine for me here. Find it below:

```
Private Sub Form_Load() 
  Dim month, day, year, hour, minute, second, nums As Integer
  Dim tmpDate As Date
  month = 6
  day = 7
  year = 2012
  hour = 6
  minute = 15
  second = 0
  nums = 10

  TChart1.Aspect.View3D = False
  TChart1.AddSeries scCandle
  TChart1.Axis.Bottom.Labels.Angle = 90

  For i = 1 To nums
    tmpDate = (DateValue(day & "," & month & "," & year) + TimeValue(hour & ":" & minute & ":" & second))
    If Not IsWeekend(tmpDate) Then
      With TChart1.Series(0)
        .asCandle.AddCandle .Count, 5, 15, 0, 10, tmpDate, clTeeColor
      End With
    End If
    day = day + 1
  Next i
End Sub

Public Function IsWeekend(InputDate As Date) As Boolean
    Select Case Weekday(InputDate)
        Case vbSaturday, vbSunday
            IsWeekend = True
        Case Else
            IsWeekend = False
    End Select
End Function
```